# Accessing Web Scripts

Tags: c#, web

I've recently been experimenting with C#s webbrowser and my curiosity has been peaked.. How does the browser actually access the webpage's code? I mean, the html, php, javascript, ajax, what have you.. How does it access it and can anyone give me a coding example of how to access it myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an awfully high level question that can only be answered with low level answers. Too much to answer with in a StackOverflow reply.

The Web Browser component is an ActiveX component that is hosted by Shdocvw.dll. [See this MSDN article about how Internet Explorer works](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741313%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

This question isn't very specific to C# at all, as the WebBrowser control does what it does the same way it does it in IE - its the same control.

If you're unfamiliar with how a browser works, sockets, TCP, or networking in general, then you may not be able to understand how it does anything that it does.

Also: PHP is a server-side language. It is processed on the server before any data it transferred to the client.

If you're after a C# example on downloading the content of a website, you can look at plenty of examples already here on StackOverflow and MSDN, namely here: [WebClient Class - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx).

Comment: Alright.. Really, what I'm actually wanting to accomplish out of this is developing a program that will monitor communications between server and client.. If there's anything more specific to that, it would be very helpful.